# How to add key listener

Tags: java, keylistener

So when I run the program it doesn't print out the variable kod. I should `addKeyListener()`; But I don't know where and how ?

Can someone please tell me how am I supposed to add the `keyListener` to my main class or where ever I am supposed to add it ???

```
import javax.swing.JFrame; 
import javax.swing.JLabel; 
import javax.swing.JPanel; 
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;


public class YuGiOh {



 public static void main(String[] args){

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("LABEL");

    frame.setSize(200,200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.addKeyListener(new tipkovnica());

    panel.setLayout(null);

    frame.add(panel);

     l1.setBounds(80,100,100,20);
     panel.add(l1);

 }
}   

class tipkovnica extends KeyAdapter{


public void keyBinder(KeyEvent e){

int kod = e.getKeyCode();

System.out.println(kod);

}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){



}

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking or trying to do. See the guidelines on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You might consider looking into using [KeyBindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than a KeyListener

Answer (score 1):

`KeyListener()` requires the component to have focus. Try adding:

`frame.requestFocus();`